# What are the different jar files for in Java, and how to import them into Eclipse?

Tags: java, jar, apache-commons-io

I just downloaded the commons-io-2.4-bin.zip and I am going to import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; and I plan to add the jars in eclipse (project->properties->Libraries->add external jars).  I know that the -javadoc.jar must contain the documentation for the commons-io library and that the -sources.java must have the source files. But I still have questions regarding what I am doing.

1. Am I including the jar files best way in eclipse
2. What are the -tests.jar and -test-sources.jar files?

Comment: ... You really ought to be using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which makes dealing with this type of thing trivially easy.  There's even a plugin on the eclipse marketplace which will pretty much auto-install it.

Comment: But I thought Maven is used after you go download the jars from other source locations.  Does maven somehow link eclipse to library repository?  Where is a fast set up tutorial?

Comment: Just install eclipse through the marketplace (Help -> Eclipse Marketplace; the integration plugin is the top item under the 'Popular' tab right now), then restart.  Create a new Maven (will also show as Java) project.  Open the .pom file, click the 'Dependencies' tab, and add the dependency there.  Done.  Yes, the plugin wires eclipse to the 'standard' library repository, which you can search and download from.

Comment: So, I File->New Project...->Maven->Maven Project.

I then leave the defaults: 
Unchecked-> "Create a simple project(Skip archetype selection)
Checked-> "Used default Workspace location"
Unchecked-> "Add project(s) to working set"
Then I click next

I now see a screen to select a Archetype from. The screen pulled lots of records with the columns "Group Id", "Artifact Id", and "Version".
It wants me to select one.  How would I know which one to select? Or should I be some how creating a new Archetype of my own?

Comment: There should be a 'quickstart' one, which will work for most general projects.

Comment: I think I figured out which one to pick. According to "Maven in 5 Minutes" http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html    They selected "maven-archetype-quickstart".  After that I followed the naming convention in their example Group Id: "com.companyname.applicationname"   Artifact Id: "application-name" The wizard then generates the package name "com.companyname.applicationame.application_name"

Comment: On on the dependencies screen there are two windows. Window1 is labeled "Dependencies" and Window2 is labeled "Dependency Management".  There is an add button on both windows.  They both have add buttons.  What are they both for?

Comment: Just use 'Dependencies', it should be all you need for now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned to use a good tool.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse, can you tell me what I should do with proprietary libraries and Maven?  I want to add a BMC library to the project.  Do I need to do something special with Maven or just add it to Eclipse like normal?

Comment: I don't know what BMC is.  If it's something internal, convert it to a maven project, then run the maven 'install' command.  This will put it in the local repository only (not upload it to the artifactory), which will make it accessible like the rest of the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should add the `.jar` file that doesn't have any suffixes to the build path.
2. Those contain unit tests (and source code for unit tests)